# How to change database name on AWS EB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Under RDS > DB Instances details, DB Name is `ebdb`. Is there any way that I can change this database name in AWS?

Answer (score -1):

If you mean the DB Instance Identifier then yes, just modify the instance (Instance Actions > Modify). Note that An outage occurs during this change. The DB instance is rebooted.